# Allow only one letter in a switch bash

Tags: bash, macos, switch-statement

I want my bash script to only accept one letter in the switch, with nothing after it.

Here's my code (foo.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash
while getopts ":ap" jeep;do
    case $jeep in
    a)
    echo 'Hi Brad'
    ;;
    b)
    echo 'Hi Eddy'
    ;;
    else)
    echo 'Hi whoever'
    \?)
    echo 'Bad input' >&2
    exit 1
    ;;
    esac
done
```

I want it to act like this:

```
$ foo.sh -a
Hi Brad

$ foo.sh -b
Hi Eddy

$ foo.sh
Hi whoever

$ foo.sh -r
Bad input

$ foo.sh -ab
Bad input

$ foo.sh -ba
Bad input
```

Instead, it runs both `a` and `b` (shown below) if I use `-ab`, which I don't want it to.

```
$ foo.sh -ab
Hi Brad
Hi Eddy
```

Also, `else)` doesn't work like I'd like it to. I want it to say `Hi whoever` if *no* switches are typed.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Erm... detect which ones are being used and error out in the case of a bad combination.

Comment: @leetbacoon why providing a non-standard behavior, if `-a` and `-b` are valid options then `-ab` and `-ba` are. Otherwise, don't use `getopts`

Comment: I want `-a` to work and `-b` to work, as well as no parameter at all, but not `-a -b`, `-ab`, `-b -a` or `-ba`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getopt` does not have a way of specifying mutually exclusive flags, so you have to create your own. The simplest way to do this is probably something like this:

```
while getopts ":ab" jeep
do
    case $jeep in
        a)
            if [ -n "${run-}" ]
            then
                exit 1
            fi
            echo 'Hi Brad'
            run=1
            ;;
        b)
            if [ -n "${run-}" ]
            then
                exit 1
            fi
            echo 'Hi Eddy'
            run=1
            ;;
        \?)
            if [ -n "${run-}" ]
            then
                exit 1
            fi
            echo 'Hi whoever'
            run=1
            ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: I typed that because I don't know how else to put "if no switches defined, then do this"

Comment: You already have the default statement - it's the `\?)` line. `case` matches are [globs](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob).

Comment: This almost works, except when I run `foo.sh -be` it says `Hi Eddy` but also `Bad input` :(